# How to separate logs from different packages

Tags: logging, go

I'm struggling to find out how to separate logs coming from different packages.

**Example:**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/org/verbose"
)

func main() {
    log.Print("Hello World")
    verbose.DoSomething() // Which will generate a lot log messages
}
```

I know there's flag `log.Llongfile` which I can enable and then each line inside the log will contain the full path of the file where is the log message coming from. This however still means I'll need to do some post-processing to filter out from that single file what I don't want and what I do want.

I'd like to do that filtering in real-time already, so I end up having `verbose-lib.log` and `my-app.log` or something like that.

I'm looking for a solution that will work with most existing OSS packages - i.e. I cannot just change logging mechanisms in these libraries in any way I want, hence custom logging libraries are out of the game I reckon.

Answer (score 2):

If the package exposes its logger to you, you can create a new logger for it with a prefix:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "example.com/lib/foo"
)

func main() {
    foo.Logger := log.New(os.Stderr, "libfoo: ", log.LstdFlags)
    // Do stuff.
}
```

This way, `foo`'s messages will look like this:

```
libfoo: 2015/09/14 17:04:52 Something's happened!
```

Additionally, `log.New` accepts an `io.Writer`, so you can open any file and make it just write there directly.

Comment: That still means I'll have to do post-processing of either one or multiple logs, won't I? I know I could use `io.MultiWriter` to write into multiple files, but to _write everything_ (twice), not filtered messages.

Comment: What kind of post-processing? If you assign each library a logger that writes to that file then all log messages from that library should be in that file. Or is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I see your point now. it will only work if the library exposes the Logger, which (from my experience) most don't.